# Ffmpeg for Windowsphone 8

Tags: ffmpeg, windows-phone-8.1

I came across this urls
1.https://github.com/pinger-inc/FFMPEG_WindowsPhone
2.https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/WinRT

I am trying to compile ffmpeg for windows phone 8. I able to compile successfully but I am missing the ffmpeg.lib file after compilation. I am trying to compile this because of the windows phone certification issue we faced while submitting to the store.

```
"The native API api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll:GetProcessTimes() isn’t allowed in assembly FFMPEGRuntime.dll. Update it and then try again."
```